# Trying to pull xml / json

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xml, json

Im having issues using trying to pull the first 15 words out of the file from the API. I have tried both as an XML and JSON and still seem to be getting this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Im using the [We feel fine API](http://www.wefeelfine.org/api.html).

Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  var WeFeelAPI = "http://api.wefeelfine.org:8080/ShowFeelings?display=json&returnfields=feeling,conditions&limit=15";

  $.getJSON( WeFeelAPI,function (json){
    var feel = json.results[15];
    console.log('Our feelings : ', feel);
  });

})();
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated i'm very new to all this, thanks

Comment: I don't think it's feeling API correctly.. Sometimes it really needs to focus to get the feelings of API..

Comment: Doesn't look like they support a remote JavaScript API... or a JSON response (they have plaintext or XML only) according to this page - http://www.wefeelfine.org/api.html

Comment: Hmm i think i'm going to struggle any advice, on how to approach it?

Comment: You won't be able to do this with JavaScript alone. You can use a server-side language like PHP to act as a proxy for JS or just cut out JS all together. If you've got PHP running on the machine hosting your page, I can whip up a quick proxy script for you.

Comment: Thanks that would be very helpful. I  will get it running now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple PHP proxy you can run along-side your page with the JavaScript

```
<?php
// Saved as ShowFeelings-proxy.php

$options = array_merge($_GET, ['display' => 'xml']);
// if you don't have PHP 5.4+, you need to use the legacy array literal syntax, eg
// array('display' => 'xml')

$uri = 'http://api.wefeelfine.org:8080/ShowFeelings?' . http_build_query($options);

$xml = simplexml_load_file($uri);

// assuming you'd rather work with JSON (I know I would)
$data = [];
foreach ($xml->feeling as $feeling) {
    $entry = [];
    foreach ($feeling->attributes() as $attr => $val) {
        $entry[$attr] = (string) $val;
    }
    $data[] = (object) $entry;
}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
exit;
```

Then in your JavaScript...

```
+function($) {
    var url = 'ShowFeelings-proxy.php',
        options = {
            'returnfields': 'feeling,conditions',
            'limit': 15
        };
    $.getJSON(url, options, function(data) {
        var feeling = data[14]; // array is zero-based
        console.log(feeling);
    });
}(jQuery);
```

Comment: This is great, it works perfect, and now i have learn't more from this. Thanks for the code, its much appreciated :)

Comment: sorry they both worked perfect, so i gave the tick to the guy who needed it more.

Answer (score 1):

Reading up on the We Feel Fine APIs, it doesn't seem like they support JSONP, or even JSON from what I can see.

The issue preventing you from calling it is known as the Same Origin Policy. It prevents a domain from making an illegal request to another domain because of the security concerns it poses. You can read on it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

JSONP (JSON with Padding) is a way for sites to work around it by loading the response a an external script that then triggers a callback function to validate the response content. This actual provides good info on SOP and JSONP: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42641/JSON-to-JSONP-Bypass-Same-Origin-Policy.

Unfortunately, the API you're using doesn't look to support JSONP so it would require the proxy approach. There is a clever/creative/maybe hackish(opinion) approach using something called Yahoo Query Language (YQL). YQL allows you to perform a x-domain request by using Yahoo's query service as the "proxy." You pass a request with a SQL-like query to it and Yahoo handles the JSONP approach. You can read about that here: http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/ (sorry for all the reading.)

And now for some code to demonstrate this. Note the QUERY being used to retrieve your XML and the fact that it must be encoded for URI use:

```
(function () {
    var url = 'http://api.wefeelfine.org:8080/ShowFeelings?display=xml&returnfields=feeling,conditions&limit=15'
    // using yahoo query
    var query = 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent('select * from xml where url="' + url + '"') + 
    '&format=json&callback=?';

    // make request via YQL and show data
    $.getJSON( query, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        // yql returns "results" in "query" from data
        console.log(data.query.results);
    });
})();
```

Play with the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ty3y2/

This same approach can actually be used to load HTML, and in fact is probably used for that more. The key is "select * from xml where..." which tells it to select everything inside the XML element found at the requested URL. Remember that XML data has a XML element at the root. Most times you will see this as "select * from html where..." because a typical web request returns HTML which is a HTML element at the root.

I have used this approach for a couple projects, though most of mine use a proxy via PHP or C#. However, I have had good success with this and it's useful when you don't want/need to put together a proxy for it.

Comment: Thankyou, this is a great work around very nice seems to work well :)